# How can I run my application on a Huawei Phone with DevEco Studio?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos, deveco-studio

I would like to use a Huawei phone emulator but the simulator only shows Tablet, TV and Smartwatch.
It seems very strange to me that the most common device is the Telephone and and that is not available.

[image]

DevEco Studio Version: 1.2.0.501

Comment: sorry for inconvenience caused, current version doesn't support phone simulator. You have to test your app in anyone of available simulators.

Comment: I can start my MatePad Pro without problems but when I touch the "Run 'entry'" button my application does not install. It also does not show me any problem, this is what I get: "09:29 AM Gradle build finished in 1 s 855 ms"

Comment: In config.json add "tablet" in deviceType section